# Split a pandas date list based on another pandas date list

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to split one date list by using another.  So:

```
d = {'date':['1/15/2015','2/15/2015'], 'num':[1,2]}
s = {'split':['2/1/2015']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
sf = pd.DataFrame(s)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
sf['split'] = pd.to_datetime(sf['split'])

df['date'].split_by(sf['split'])
```

would yield:

```
        date    num
0 2015-01-15    1.0
1 2015-02-01    NaN  
2 2015-02-15    2.0
```

...but of course, it doesn't.  I'm sure there's a simple merge or join I'm missing here, but I can't figure it out.  Thanks.

Also, if the `'split'` list has multiple dates, some of which fall outside the range of the `'date'` list, I don't want them included.  So basically, the extents of the new range would be the same as the old.

*(side note: if there's a better way to convert a dictionary to a DataFrame and immediately convert the date strings to datetimes, that would be icing on the cake)*

Comment: I first think you need `df = pd.concat([df, sf]).sort_values('date')`, but it seems not. So if values in sf is in range max date of df and min value of df are added to output?

Comment: @jezrael - Right, split the dates only if the `sf` value is within the min/max of `df['date']`.  I also just added another column to `df` to show that there is other data in the DataFrame I want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter `sf` by `min` and `max` of column `date` in `df` first and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), for align need rename column:

```
d = {'date':['1/15/2015','2/15/2015'], 'num':[1,2]}
s = {'split':['2/1/2015', '2/1/2016', '2/1/2014']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
sf = pd.DataFrame(s)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
sf['split'] = pd.to_datetime(sf['split'])
print (df)
        date  num
0 2015-01-15    1
1 2015-02-15    2

print (sf)
       split
0 2015-02-01
1 2016-02-01
2 2014-02-01
```

```
mask = (sf.split <= df.date.max()) & (sf.split >= df.date.min())
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: split, dtype: bool

sf = sf[mask]
print (sf)
       split
0 2015-02-01

df = pd.concat([df, sf.rename(columns={'split':'date'})]).sort_values('date')
print (df)
        date  num
0 2015-01-15  1.0
0 2015-02-01  NaN
1 2015-02-15  2.0
```

Comment: Nailed it!  Check's in the mail.  Thanks jezrael.